# Where to change SSL Thumbprint in Solr

Tags: solr

As I need to change the SSL Thumbprint in Solr configuration. I am new to Solr configration. Please help me to get the related configuration in Solr.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show what errors you are encountering?

Comment: No I am not getting any error because I have not changed it yet.  I am unable to find the thumbprint configuration in Solr.  Please let me know the configuration file name. @MichaelWest

Answer (score 1):

### If you want to use the Self Signed Cert, then follow the below steps:

1. Open a Windows PowerShell as an administrator and navigate to: `<Path_to_Solr_Folder>\server\etc`
2. Run this command in Windows PowerShell to create a Keystore file named `solr-ssl.keystore.jks` in the current directory.:

```
C:\'Program Files'\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin\keytool.exe -genkeypair -alias solr-ssl -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keypass secret -storepass secret -validity 9999 -keystore solr-ssl.keystore.jks -ext SAN=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1 -dname "CN=localhost, OU=Organizational Unit, O=Organization, L=Location, ST=State, C=Country"
```

Check if `solr-ssl.keystore.jks` file is created in 'etc' folder.

You might get this warning while running the above command, which should be resolved in next step:

```
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore 
-srckeystore solr-ssl.keystore.jks -destkeystore solr-ssl.keystore.jks -deststoretype pkcs12".
```

3. Run this command to Convert the Certificate and Key to PEM Format

```
C:\'Program Files'\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin\keytool.exe -importkeystore -srckeystore solr-ssl.keystore.jks -destkeystore solr-ssl.keystore.p12 -srcstoretype jks -deststoretype pkcs12 -deststorepass secret -srcstorepass secret
```

You'll get this success message.
[image]

4. Import(double click) generated certificate file `solr-ssl.keystore.p12` that was created in the `~\server\etc` directory. Match the values below when prompt

- Store Location: Local Machine
- Password: secret
- Certificate store: Trusted Root Certificate Authorities

5. Update the `~\bin\solr.in.cmd` file by pasting the following code block at the end of the file.

```
set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE=etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD=secret
set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_TYPE=JKS
set SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE=etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
set SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=secret
set SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_TYPE=JKS
set SOLR_SSL_NEED_CLIENT_AUTH=false
set SOLR_SSL_WANT_CLIENT_AUTH=false
```

6. Add following Lines to `~\bin\solr.in.sh`

```
SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE=etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD=secret
SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_TYPE=JKS
SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE=etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=secret
SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_TYPE=JKS
SOLR_SSL_NEED_CLIENT_AUTH=false
SOLR_SSL_WANT_CLIENT_AUTH=false
```

7. Restart solr service.

### If you want to  use CA-signed certs

1. Convert your CA cert into .PFX and place it in `<solr directory>/server/etc` folder.
2. Update solr.in.cmd File `<solr directory>/bin/solr.in.cmd`

```
set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE=C:\<solr directory>\server\etc\new_solr_ssl_cert.pfx
set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD=secret123
set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_TYPE=PKCS12
set SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE=C:\<solr directory>\server\etc\new_solr_ssl_cert.pfx
set SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=secret123
set SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_TYPE=PKCS12
```

3. Restart the Solr service.

Comment: Are there existing answers on SSE that you could of referenced? Perhaps your solution could have been answered on one of those and then question flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: Sure, @MichaelWest. Will do that :)